# how to make sure that when you restart the game, the scene that was active when you turned off the game is loaded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

I'm making a horror game and at the very beginning of the game there is a long precondition, it turned out not bad, but if it happens every time you enter the game, it will irritate me, so I want it to play when I first start it, and when I start it again I read the scene where the game was turned off, this is also will solve the issue with saves because if the player has reached level 2, then the game will start from there when logging in again

I understand that you can use PlayerPrefs and I even tried to do this, but when I reached the level at which the game should be saved, it began to restart many times, not being able to proceed normally. I have very little time left, so I won’t have time to figure it out myself and would I’m very grateful if you send me the finished code with detailed explanations of what needs to be done so that I can just copy what you wrote, thanks in advance

Here is an example of my code that doesn’t work. I’ll be glad if you fix it and send me the finished one or give me yours.
Thank you

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string activeSceneName;

    void Start()
    {
        activeSceneName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("ActiveScene", "DefaultSceneName");
        StartCoroutine(LoadSavedScene());
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        activeSceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("ActiveScene", activeSceneName);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    IEnumerator LoadSavedScene()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); // Wait for a short time to allow the scene to load           completely
        SceneManager.LoadScene(activeSceneName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the descriptions of tags you add to your question. C and C# are very different languages.

Answer (score 1):

don't call "LoadSavedScene()" if the saved scene is the same as the one you are currently in.

```
    void Start()
    {
        activeSceneName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("ActiveScene", "DefaultSceneName");
        if (activeSceneName != SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name) 
        {
            StartCoroutine(LoadSavedScene());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now when I get to the scene that should be saved, the first one starts instead. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I created a  GameObject on the scene that should be saved and threw a script on it

Comment: is the Start() code running when you enter the scene that need to be saved? instead of loading the scene in Start() when a level actually get loaded you could just directly load the right level from playerprefs from you game's main menu